# How to understand the derivation of thermally averaged cross sections?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, electrons, dark-matter, scattering-cross-section

$$
\frac{d\langle\sigma_\text{ion}^{nl} v\rangle}{d\ln E_\text{er}}=\frac{\bar\sigma_e}{8\mu^2_{\chi e}}\int q|f_\text{ion}^{nl}(k',q)|^2|F_\text{DM}(q)|^2\eta(v_\text{min})\ dq
$$

How do I understand the derivation of thermally averaged cross sections like this equation? What basic tools do I need to understand it? I have studied scattering cross sections, but I don't understand this equation above. Is it called the thermally averaged cross section？

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Where did you get this from, some paper or book? There at least the variable names would be defined... this doesn't look so much like the cosmological cross section to me at all, looks more like the rate you would get in a direct detection experiment looking for electron scatters...

Comment: Sir, Thanks for your comment, I indeed get it from a paper about direct detection. And I am a second year undergraduate student major in physics. Since lack of indepth knowledge, I am quite confused about the derivation of this equation. Could you recommend some books or papers on the derivation. Thank you sincerely.

Comment: Hi, which paper? then i proably can help better

Comment: Also, check out section II in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9803295 does that help you at all? Note that that paper is about nuclear recoils whereas if my guess is right then your equation deals with electronic recoils.

Comment: The papers are all about direct detection of dark matter （main author: Rouven Essig）. Sir ,thanks for your genuine help. I will check the paper your gave out. Thanks again.

Comment: Again, give me a link to work with and I can have a look; Rouven is an expert in particular in direct detection of dark matter via electron scattering so my guess from above is likely correct ;)

Comment: The equation is taken from this paper: http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.85.076007； your intuition is correct XD.

Answer (score 0):

This equation does not describe a thermally averaged annihilation cross section as one would expect in a cosmological context. Instead, it is used to discuss the expected rate of electronic recoils in a direct detection experiment as function of energy. The OP took the equation from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.5383) (Eq. 5), where it is indeed referenced in a somewhat confusing way.

A more thorough derivation is given by the same authors in [chapter 6.1 of this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.14521). I refer to this discussion for details and the actual derivation.

More qualitatively, the equation can be understood as follows: Given is the differential cross section per (logarithmic) unit energy; this is essentially the resulting recoil spectrum. The factor in front of the integral is just some average cross-section and the reduced mass of the dark matter-electron system, which enters as in any classical scattering calculation. The rate as function of energy is often described as an integral over all transferred momenta $q$ that contribute to that recoil energy $E_{er}$. In addition to the transferred momentum $q$ itself, three terms are under the integral: The first here describes the form factor for ionization $f$, i.e. something akin to the likelihood of ionizing the atom; this is relevant here since the paper concerns itself with the (somewhat niche) idea of dark matter ionizing a target. The second term $F$ is the form factor for dark matter scattering itself; for example decoherence due to high momenta are taken into account here, or if the scattering was momentum-dependent. The third term $\eta$ is a step function that selects just those minimal galactic speeds out of the dark matter velocity distribution that are required to give the desired recoil energy.

Personally I found the derivation [in section II of this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9803295) clear to follow the individual steps in deriving the differential rate in a direct detection experiment. Note that this paper concerns itself with nuclear recoils, so in contrast to the equation posted by the OP, the target is the nucleus and not the electron, and there is no form factor for ionization, which simplifies the discussion. I recommend to first understand that before diving into electron scattering.